# How does a php script run without reloading the page

Tags: php, database

This seems a little vague, but you see this a lot. For instance on facebooks notification system, it will display the total notifications on the top. StackOverflow does the samething on the questions page, Youtube does the same thing in the comment section. I guess my question really is, how does the page interact with a database without reloading the page?

Comment: via something called AJAX

Comment: With [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: Just voting for non-constructive because I'm tooo lazy to search up the duplicate for you. Just search before asking. If your problem looks like something common, there is a great chance you find information about that already on site.

Answer (score 6):

It's called AJAX. There is a javascript code that runs in the background every X seconds, and that code makes an http request to the server to get the up-to-date data. Once it get the response from the server, the javascript code updates the web page to display the new data.

Comment: so essentially ajax isnt a new language, its just a combination of javascript and xml?

Comment: Yup - though there are many that use JSON instead of XML.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of them are relying on [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX). Before AJAX existed, a common method was to post data to a hidden iframe on the page, thus refreshing the iframe instead of the whole page.

AJAX is made possible by [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript), although most people prefer using a [framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) to avoid handling the browser compatibility issues that may rise.

For quick response, some sites (including Facebook) use a variant of the Jabber protocol ([now XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol)), which lets the server push information to the client, instead of the client polling the server every X seconds. This can lighten the load on the server dramatically, especially if the site has a lot of users.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of javascript called AJAX runs. It allows you to effectively load pages in the background and execute code on them without leaving the main page.

You request another .php page typically with some variables entered by a user or got from a database, and that PHP page then processes the data. You can then update your main page elements using document.getElementById or similar.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

This page helps to explain it a lot.